# How to make use of Threads optional in a Julia function

Tags: julia

I have a function that optionally uses threads for its main loop, doing so when an argument `usingthreads` is `true`. At the moment, the code looks like this:

```
function dosomething(usingthreads::Bool)
    n = 1000
    if usingthreads
        Threads.@threads for i = 1:n
            #20 lines of code here
        end
    else
        for i = 1:n
            #same 20 lines of code repeated here
        end
    end
end
```

Less nasty than the above would be to put the "20 lines" in a separate function. Is there another way?

Comment: what version of Julia?
Julia 1.3 significantly enhances threading, and would make some of this easier

Comment: I haven't yet experimented with 1.3, still on 1.2

Comment: For this specific usecase I think the method you've described works fine.  However, if you want to incorporate thread-specific optimizations, you might want to do something like this:

```julia
function dosomething(::Val{false}) # nonthreaded case
    # implementation here
end

function dosomething(::Val{true}) # nonthreaded case
    # threaded implementation here
end

dosomething(usethreads::Bool) = dosomething(Val(usethreads))

```
Would this be good style?

Answer (score 4):

You could use a macro that changes its behavior depending on the result of `Threads.nthreads()`:

```
macro maybe_threaded(ex)
    if Threads.nthreads() == 1
        return esc(ex)
    else
        return esc(:(Threads.@threads $ex))
    end
end
```

Without threading, this macro will be a no-op:

```
julia> @macroexpand @maybe_threaded for i in 1:5
           print(i)
       end
:(for i = 1:5
      #= REPL[2]:2 =#
      print(i)
  end)
```

But when threading is enabled and e.g. `JULIA_NUM_THREADS=4` it will expand to the threaded version:

```
julia>  @maybe_threaded for i in 1:5
           print(i)
       end
41325
```

Edit: Upon rereading the question, I realize this doesn't really answer it but it might be useful anyway.

Comment: You're doubly correct: a) it doesn't (quite) answer my question, b) I might well find it useful, particularly as I've not yet written any macros.

Comment: Why doesn't the `@threads` macro work like that by default, BTW? I have the impression that threading carries some overhead that could be avoided like this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ThreadsX](https://github.com/tkf/ThreadsX.jl) as suggested in [this discourse link](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/optionally-multi-threaded-for-loop/81902/7?u=skleinbo).

The answer from the thread (all credit to oxinabox):

```
using ThreadsX

function foo(multi_thread=true)
    _foreach = multi_thread ? ThreadsX.foreach : Base.foreach
    _foreach(1:10) do ii
        @show ii
    end
end
```